# Plugin appends ugly URL string to index

Tags: plugins, permalinks, url-rewriting

A custom background plugin has started to cause certain browsers (FF, IE8,9, Safari) to reveal an appended URL string when viewing the index page: http://dearearth.net - this mostly shows when not visiting the site directly, but rather when going through, for example, Google.

This persists in IE 9 even after refresh or page reload, but does not on the other browsers.

Screenshot:

[image]

I have the following custom permalink structure enabled:`/%category%/%postname%/`

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have to be a plugin issue.

If someone puts a link on their website to your blog say for example: www.example.com but not only that they place some random string: www.example.com/?foo=bar in that link to your site then when search engines crawl this page with the link to your site on google or any other search engine will see it and try to follow the link to your website.

As is the URL is technically valid the search engine will cache it and serve this new URL to its users.

Have a read over this post at Perishable Press that talks about it in detail.

http://perishablepress.com/clean-up-links-htaccess/

Comment: @Brady However, this happens to be a plugin issue! If you go directly to the site through IE9, the string appears. When the plugin is disabled.. surprise... the string ceases to appear.

Comment: @vulgarbulgar no the string appears for me in any browser... what plugin is causing this?

Comment: @vulgarbulgar it seems to appear if I'm being referred from a website that it appears. So if I click the link from this site the url changes. But if I type it in manually I dont get the code.

Comment: @Brady This plugin: http://codecanyon.net/item/custom-backgrounds-for-wordpress/121983

Comment: @Brady As someone suggested, I did reset the permalink settings, several times, to no avail.

Comment: @vulgarbulgar sorry but there is nothing I can assist with further. The plugin is not free so unable to get access to source code to see what is going on.

Comment: @Brady They are releasing anew version next week. They have just sent a pre-release for me to test out. I will get back here with any updates. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @Brady - http://plugins.righthere.com/custom-backgrounds/multiple-schedule/?cbg_tz=480

Comment: @Brady This is an integral part of the plugin, whereby, using js, it detects the browser timezone,a dn thereby sets the according scheduled background... As you suggested int he referencing URL, it's best to simply edit the .htaccess with a permanent redirect,s tripping the string.. which will also help with those dupes in analytics. Thanks.